# How to change listbox instead of list view

Tags: vb6

Below code is working for list view, but i want to use listbox instead of list view

lst = listview from the below code

```
Dim idx as integer
    idx = 1
        lst.ListItems.Clear
        If Emp.Employees.RecordCount > 0 Then
            Emp.Employees.MoveFirst
            While Not Employees.EOF
                lst.ListItems.Add idx, , EmployeeID
                lst.ListItems(idx).ListSubItems.Add , , FirstName
                If IsAssigned(EmployeeID, CurrentSchedule) Then
                    lst.ListItems(idx).Checked = True
                Else
                    lst.ListItems(idx).Checked = False
                End If
                 idx = idx + 1
                Employees.MoveNext
            Wend
        End If
```

Listbox name is lstbox

I tried

`lstbox.selected(I) = true` is not working instead of `lst.ListItems(idx).Checked = True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with aListbox
    .Clear
    '//loop here
        .additem "The Item Text"
        '//add the numeric id value
        .itemdata(.NewIndex) = 112233
        '//check it
        if (condition) then
            .Selected(.NewIndex) = True
        end if
end with

'//sample click
msgbox aListbox.list(aListbox.listindex) & " id=" & aListbox.itemdata(aListbox.listindex)
```

Comment: You also need to set the `.Style` property to `vbListBoxCheckbox` to show the checks.